# How to count some rows in a specific field in mysql table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to get some statistics like below:

```
--------------------------------------
NAME    HIGH    MEDIUM    LOW    TOTAL
--------------------------------------
ali     2       0         1      3
hacen   1       1         0      2
--------------------------------------
```

from table TASKS

```
----------------------------------
NAME     ASSIGNED-TO     PERIORITY
----------------------------------
task-1   ali             high
task-2   ali             high
task-3   ali             low
task-4   hacen           high
task-5   hacen           medium
----------------------------------
```

using codeigniter 3

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Comment: why i see -2 beside my question, what does this mean?

Comment: @hassanali It means that others have deemed your question as "does not show research effort; it is unclear; or unuseful"

Comment: Your question has been down voted because you didn't follow the rules. See the link in my comment above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` statement with the aggregate functions `SUM` and `COUNT`.

**Query**

```
SELECT `ASSIGNED-TO` AS `NAME`,
SUM(CASE `PRIORITY` WHEN 'high' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `High`,
SUM(CASE `PRIORITY` WHEN 'medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Medium`,
SUM(CASE `PRIORITY` WHEN 'low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Low`,
COUNT(*) AS `Total`
FROM `tasks`
GROUP BY `ASSIGNED-TO`;
```

Comment: @hassanali : If it solved your issue, then it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Here would be an example MySQL query, which could accomplish what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  `ASSIGNED-TO` AS `NAME`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN priority = "high" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `HIGH`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN priority = "medium" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `MEDIUM`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN priority = "low" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `LOW`,
  COUNT(*) AS `TOTAL`
FROM `TASKS`
GROUP BY `ASSIGNED-TO`
```